# How to dynamically specify the name of a static file?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a report.html template in which I need to dynamically change the name of images. I've done a lot of research and trial and error. But I just can't get the URLs for the images to be correct.

The images are in /templates/users/reports/rptemplate/images.

After researching static images, I also copied the images to:

/static/images.

Here's my latest html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

{% load staticfiles %} 

<html>
...

              <img alt="" src="static/images/{{img_vision}}">
...
```

This is my report view:

```
class UserReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/reports/rptemplate/report.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #context = super(DisplayTaskView, self).get_context_data(kwargs)
            #TODO: retrieve the actual data
        context = {'sid': 519893,
        'church_name': 'Lakeview Bible',
        'report_date': '5 Feb 2018',
        'responses': 57,
        'img_vision': 'image1.png',
        'img_leadership': 'image1.png',
        'img_mobilization': 'image1.png',
        'img_stewardship': 'image1.png',
        'img_context': 'image1.png',
        'img_evangelism': 'image1.png',
        'img_discipleship': 'image1.png',
        'img_service': 'image1.png',
        'img_fellowship': 'image1.png',
        'img_worship': 'image1.png',
        'img_category': 'image1.png',
        'img_radar': 'image1.png'
        }  
        return context
```

And this is my user/url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^$',
        view=views.UserListView.as_view(),
        name='list'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^~redirect/$',
        view=views.UserRedirectView.as_view(),
        name='redirect'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        view=views.UserDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^~update/$',
        view=views.UserUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='update'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^reports/rptemplate/$',
        view=views.UserReportView.as_view(),
        name='report'
    ),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

So where is my mistake? How do I dynamically specify the name of a static file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do dynamically: get all the images within a certain directory, or to build a url to the image within a forloop?

Comment: I'm retrieving data from limesurvey and generating graphs. There are 10 graphs per report. And of course, multiple users can request the graph at the same time. So the images need to be generated with different files names for each user + graph combination.

Comment: Have you tried <img alt="" src="/static/images/{{img_vision}}"> note the extra slash before static

Comment: @Anshul Dang! That was it. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<img alt="" src="/static/images/{{img_vision}}">` 
*Note the extra slash before static.